# Obtain Exclusive Process Handle

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

I am writing an app in C# and C++/CLI, and I have code that suspends processes. However, I want to prevent them from being un-suspended by another process (such as Process Explorer). Is it possible to obtain an exclusive process handle or otherwise somehow block other applications from performing this operation? And if so, how?

Comment: The best direction I can give you would be to look at the MSDN documentation on [Process Security and Access Rights](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880(v=vs.85).aspx). You might be able to modify the ACLs of the processes you are suspending to prevent any other processes from un-suspending it. Then, when you want to un-suspend it, you'd modify the ACL again, un-suspend, and then restrict the ACL again. However, other processes with high enough privileges (like `SeDebugPrivilege`, which your app would likely need too) might still override your restrictions.

Comment: And for what it's worth, just getting `SeDebugPrivilege` for your own app can be quite a challenge! My recollection is that your app needs to be running as the `SYSTEM` user to have enough privileges to modify its own privilege list.

Comment: @ozeanix, not if you're doing it right.  Any process running with administrator privileges can enable debug privilege.  (Well, in the default configuration, anyway.)

Comment: There is no "sharing mode" for process handles.  You would need to change the ACLs *and ownership* for the process and presumably for all of its threads.  This wouldn't affect an administrative user, of course.  It might be possible to block access in kernel mode somehow, but there's little point.

Comment: @HarryJohnston you're right about `SeDebugPrivilege` - I was thinking of `SeTcbPrivilege` and `SeAssignPrimaryToken` instead. It's been a long time since I needed to remember those!

Comment: @ozeanix - if we have `SeDebugPrivilege` we can open token or thread from LocalSystem process and impersonate. so if we have `SeDebugPrivilege` we can got all privilege under windows.

Comment: @ozeanix am I correct in assuming that `SeDebugPrivilege` is an edge case? How would I go about writing code in C# that allows me to modify the ACL of a process and prevent my changes being overriden?

Comment: @333 It won't help do what you're asking. @RbMm's answer is correct to the best of my knowledge, you'd need a kernel driver to do what you want. The case I mentioned was to hide my C# program from a Windows service that was scanning the memory of other processes. By running as `SYSTEM` and elevating my privileges I was able to modify the ACL of my own program to sufficiently hide it, and make the Windows service fail to use `ReadProcessMemory` on my program. But that's totally different from what you're trying to do. Sorry if my side discussion lead to your confusion :(

Answer (score 4):

this is impossible do from user mode.

any process which have `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` enabled in token can open process/thread handle with all access (only if it not protected process).

from kernel mode you can register own callback with [`ObRegisterCallbacks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558692(v=vs.85).aspx) and filter process/threads open attempt. say deny handle open or remove `PROCESS_SUSPEND_RESUME`, `THREAD_SUSPEND_RESUME` and `THREAD_RESUME` from `DesiredAccess` in [`OB_PRE_CREATE_HANDLE_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558725(v=vs.85).aspx). but this not prevent another kernel mode code call exported api `PsResumeProcess`.

in general object handles partially support exclusive access. look for `OBJ_EXCLUSIVE` flag in [`OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557749(v=vs.85).aspx) (this is always passed as 3-rd parameter to any open/create object call - [`ZwOpenProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567022(v=vs.85).aspx) as well) but this will be work only *if the `OBJ_EXCLUSIVE` flag was set when the object was created.* otherwise you got [`STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`](https://github.com/bigzz/WRK/blob/master/base/ntos/ob/obhandle.c#L1635) or if handle already opened by another process , you got [`STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`](https://github.com/bigzz/WRK/blob/master/base/ntos/ob/obhandle.c#L1647). but because processes always created without `OBJ_EXCLUSIVE` flag - you and can not open it handle in exclusive (i already not say about that in `csrss.exe` related to process session already exist open handle to your process)

Answer (score 0):

You can inject code into another running process and patch the NtResumeProcess and NtResumeThread routines exported by NTDLL. The exported routines will perform a system-call however you can intercept before this transition occurs and redirect execution to your own callback routine to apply filtering - return STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED or another appropriate NTSTATUS error code to block the operation.

This won't prevent someone from bypassing your patch with a manual system call though. Your best bet is ObRegisterCallbacks and then stripping PROCESS_SUSPEND_RESUME for any caller other than yourself.

The first method via run-time byte patching is fine because user-mode hooking isn't a concern as long as it's done properly. There are also open-source libraries for accomplishing this, Microsoft own their own API hooking library named MS Detours as well. The ObRegisterCallbacks method will require a kernel-mode device driver, and with this comes the necessity for a digital signature which supports kernel-mode software signing (and for support on systems which have Secure Boot enabled, you'll need an Extended Validation signature which is only issued to genuinely registered companies and is a lot pricier).

Good luck.